# Python Get top values in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary called `wordCounts` which maps a word to how many times it occurred, how can I get the top `n` words in the dict while allowing more than `n` if there is a tie?

Comment: By "top" I assume you mean highest word count?

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far.

Comment: @Soviut yes, that is correct. I have never used python, and I've got a feeling there may be a built in function for this.

Answer (score 3):

As the previous answer says, you can cast as a `Counter` to make this dataset easier to deal with.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> d = {"d":1,"c":2,"a":3,'b':3,'e':0,'f':1}
>>> c = Counter(d)
>>> c
Counter({'b': 3, 'a': 3, 'c': 2, 'f': 1, 'd': 1, 'e': 0})
```

`Counter` has a `most_common(n)` method that will take the `n` most common elements. Note that it will *exclude* ties. Therefore:

```
>>> c.most_common(4)
[('b', 3), ('a', 3), ('c', 2), ('f', 1)]
```

To *include* all values equal to the nth element, you can do something like the following, without converting to a `Counter`. This is pretty messy, but it should do the trick.

```
from collections import Counter

def most_common_inclusive(freq_dict, n):
    # find the nth most common value
    nth_most_common = sorted(c.values(), reverse=True)[n-1]
    return { k: v for k, v in c.items() if v >= nth_most_common }
```

You can use as follows:

```
>>> d = {'b': 3, 'a': 3, 'c': 2, 'f': 1, 'd': 1, 'e': 0}
>>> most_common_inclusive(d, 4)
{'d': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 2, 'f': 1, 'a': 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict


list_of_words = ['dog', 'cat', 'moo', 'dog', 'pun', 'pun']
def get_n_most_common(n, list_of_words):
    ct = Counter(list_of_words)
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for word, quantity in ct.items():
        d[quantity].append(word)
    most_common = sorted(d.keys(), reverse= True)
    return [(word, val) for val in most_common[:n] for word in d[val]]
```

And the tests:

```
 >> get_n_most_common(2, list_of_words)
 => [('pun', 2), ('dog', 2), ('moo', 1), ('cat', 1)]
 >> get_n_most_common(1, list_of_words)
 => [('pun', 2), ('dog', 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

MooingRawr is on the right track, but now we need to just get the top `n` results

```
l = []
for i, (word, count) in enumerate(sorted(d.items(), reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1])):  
    if i >= n and count<l[-1][1]:
        break
    l.append((word, count))
```

Comment: I would amend to `for i, (word, count) in enumerate(...)` and then use `i >= n`

Comment: @brianpck excellent point. I knew there was a better way, but todays been a slow day for me